# 'raise_Exception' error in translate package

Tags: pandas, google-translate, translate

guys I'm trying to translate a column of my data called Task and facing problems. First I try to use googletrans

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
!pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1 
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
df['Spanish'] = df['Task'].apply(translator.translate, src='en', dest='es').apply(getattr, args=('text',))
df
```

got this error:

```
--> 122         if r.status_code != 200 and self.raise_Exception:
    123             raise Exception('Unexpected status code "{}" from {}'.format(
    124                 r.status_code, self.service_urls))

AttributeError: 'Translator' object has no attribute 'raise_Exception'
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `time.sleep(1)` helped me resolve it.

Comment: How would work? like this?@Amey

df['Spanish'] = df['Task'].apply(translator.translate, src='en', dest='es').apply(getattr, args=('text',))

time.sleep(1)

df

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).